# target last element with specific class

Tags: css

I have several divs generated by php which contain childs with the class `.child` (amongst others div with different classes).
Here is a simplified sample of what it looks like :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="other-class"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="other-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-class"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="other-class"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="other-class"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to target the last div with the class `.child` of every `.container` in my page in order to modify to its margins and a few other tweaks.

Since it is generated by php, I can't predict where the divs with the class `.child` will appear nor how many of them will be generated. It depends on the data in my sql database.

Also, a user can add a new div with the class `.child` at the bottom of `.container` through ajax, and in this case the css would no longer target the current last `.child` but the new one generated by the user.

I've tried several of things with css (last-child, last-of-type... etc) but I couldn't successfully target my divs.
This thread is a duplicate (I've consulted many others) but they are all 4+ years old and mostly bring jquery alternatives.
Is there anything new to actually do this with css ?

Comment: the duplicate link provides an alternative solution  to target the first element which doesn't seem adaptable to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
.container .child:last-child
```

Comment: hello, this is indeed the very first thing I tried. It wouldn't work however.

Answer (score 0):

try to this:

```
.container > div:last-child { }
```

Comment: It won't work, since the last div doesn't necessarily have the class `.child` :(